# Calendario con Datetimepicker- cambiar horarios dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, datetimepicker

Necesito cambiar el horario dinámicamente según la fecha seleccionada, alguna recomendación?
Tengo un array de horarios de 09am a 03 am, el cual mediante indexof voy eliminando ciertos horarios que traigo de la bases de datos mediante la comparacion. El array sigue siendo horarios, con ciertos horarios eliminados, y mostraria en pantalla solo los disponibles. Alguna otra forma? porque no me estaria funcionando mi metodo.

```
      let horarios = ['9:00', '10:00', '11:00', 
            '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00',
            '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00',
            '22:00', '23:00','00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00'];
      $("#nueva_reserva_cancha").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'buscoCancha',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                        'nombreCancha': $("#nueva_reserva_cancha").val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      $.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
                      $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
                          format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
                          yearStart: 2022,    
                          yearEnd: 2030,
                          dayOfWeekStart:1,
                          allowTimes: horarios,
                          onSelectDate:function(ct,$i){
                            var time = $(this);                                
                              fechaSeleccionada = JSON.stringify(moment(ct).format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE))
                              console.log("fecha: "+fechaSeleccionada);
                              //capturo fecha y dia, de los registros de la bases de datos
                               for(h of data){
                                  capturoFechaBd= JSON.stringify(moment(h.fecha).format(moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE));
                                  capturoHoraBd = moment(h.fecha).format("HH:mm");
                                  if((capturoFechaBd === fechaSeleccionada)){
                                      console.log("La fecha existe");
                                      var indice = horarios.indexOf(capturoHoraBd);
                                      horarios.splice(indice,1);
                                      this.setOptions({
                                      allowTimes: horarios
                                  });
                                    console.log(indice);
                                    console.log(time);
                                  }
                                } //for
                          }//fin onSelect    
                     });//fin datetimepicker
                  }// fin success
            });//finaliza ajax
      }); // fin nueva_reserva_cancha
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la funcion indexof funciona perfecto, le problema que surge es que al seleccionar otra fecha sin horarios registrados en la bases de datos,  el panel de horas sigue trayendo los datos de la fecha anterior seleccionada, se que puede ser algun problema del if, pero no encuentro solución.

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/519571/edit) para poner el código como texto en vez de imagen. Solo así podemos analizar o copiar y pegar para probar.

Comment: trata de poner tu codigo completo para tener un [mcve] y convertirlo a snippet